# Why am I getting "The subscription number xxxxx cannot be found" as a response to AcquireTokenAsync?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-mobile-services

I am using AAD authentication. I've read through several examples, and everything seems to be set up correctly, but I cannot log in.  Using Fiddler, I was able to discover that a "The subscription  could not be found' message is sent as a response by Azure when AcquireTokenAsync executes in my client app.  The number that is included in the message is the wrong subscription number.  I'm guessing it's an old subscription that I have deleted. I only have one active subscription.  My question is how does the client code determine what subscription number to send?  Can I change this?  I only have the default active directory.  My service app, client app, and AAD all seem to be set to the current subscription.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Some code would be useful, so we can point out if there is something wrong. Could you add relevant code?

Comment: This has been solved.  I have no idea how.  But I no longer get the error.  Thanks for your time.